# IOS after post request get error with additional symbol "\"

Tags: ios, swift, api, response

I want to make a post request to my server. But when I get the response the server says that I sent wrong data. My code where i make the request is :

```
let urlAddress = Constants.API_DOMEN + Constants.SOC_LOGIN_ENDING
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL : NSURL(string: urlAddress)!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"        

let params = [Constants.NAME : name,
              Constants.EMAIL: email,
              Constants.PROVIDER: provider,
              Constants.UID: userId,
              Constants.PHONE_NUMBER: phoneNumber,
              Constants.AVATAR: photoURL,
              Constants.TYPE: "3",
              Constants.KEY: getMD5Hash(userId, provider: provider)]
            as Dictionary<String, String>

request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
....
```

But when i get the response

```
...
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
            guard data != nil else {
                print("no data found: \(error)")
                return
            }

            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
.....
```

I see :

```
 dataString NSString?   "{\"head\": {\"errcode\": 400}, \"postdata\": 
    {\"oe\": [\"57AE2750\\\",\\\"phone\\\":\\\"\\\",
    \\\"name\\\":\\\"\\u0418\\u043b\\u044c\\u044f \\u041c\\u044f\\u0441\\u043e\\u0435\\u0434\\u043e\\u0432\\\",
    \\\"provider\\\":\\\"facebook\\\",
    \\\"uid\\\":\\\"236653050055667\\\",
    \\\"type\\\":\\\"3\\\",
    \\\"key\\\":\\\"b182111b0cf5d2b0e652675eac544490\\\"}\"], \"{\\\"email\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"avatar\\\":
\\\"https:\\\\/\\\\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\\\\/hprofile-xfa1\\\\/v\\\\/t1.0-1\\\\/s200x200\\\\/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh\": [\"e809266ec7a9e37c304ff6ec183b735b\"]},
 \"error\": {\"name\": 401, \"type\": 401,
 \"uid\": 401, \"key\": 401, \"provider\": 401}}"
```

1) In field name I get wrong symbols.I suppose that something wrong with encoding here.

2) IOS is adding symbol "\" to every quote. But I can't understand why.

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Here "\" is used as escape sequence character. It is appeared after special character.

Comment: @RichardG , yes but in 
this case should be something 
like this "{\"uid:\":\"236653050055667\"},{\"provider\":\" facebook\"}"

Comment: it would be best if you add code which parses received JSON and creates an error object if this JSON represents an error. Also loggin response should help, HTTP headers also contain useful information about error reported by server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The right way to make a post request is shown below. I have added the complete function:

```
class func socialSignIn(name : String!, email: String!, provider: String!, userId: String!, photoURL: String!, phoneNumber: String!){
        var globalSuccess:Bool = false
        let urlAddress = Constants.API_DOMEN + Constants.SOC_LOGIN_ENDING
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL : NSURL(string: urlAddress)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        var postString = Constants.NAME + "=" + name + "&";
        postString = postString + Constants.EMAIL + "=" + email + "&";
        postString = postString + Constants.PROVIDER + "=" + provider + "&";
        postString = postString + Constants.UID + "=" + userId + "&";
        postString = postString + Constants.PHONE_NUMBER + "=" + phoneNumber + "&";
        postString = postString + Constants.AVATAR + "=" + photoURL + "&";
        postString = postString + Constants.TYPE + "=" + "3" + "&";
        postString = postString + Constants.KEY + "=" + getMD5Hash(userId, provider: provider);


        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
            guard data != nil else {
                print("no data found: \(error)")
                return
            }            

            //get user cookies
            let sessionId = getSessionId(response!)
            PreferencesHelper.setAuthToken(sessionId)

            do {
                if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary{
                    let success = json.objectForKey("head")?.objectForKey("errcode") as? Int
                    if success == Constants.SUCCESS {
                        globalSuccess = true
                    }
                    print("Success: \(success)")
                }else{
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)    // No error thrown, but not NSDictionary
                    print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                }
            } catch let parseError{
                print(parseError)                                                          // Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            }

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(ViewController.notificationResult, object: nil, userInfo:[Constants.SUCCESS:globalSuccess ])
        }


        task.resume()
}
```

The function that gets the session id looks like:

```
class func getSessionId(response: NSObject)->String{
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse{
            if let headers = httpResponse.allHeaderFields as? [String:String], url = httpResponse.URL{
                let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(headers, forURL: url)
                for cookie in cookies{
                    var cookieProperties = [String: AnyObject]()
                    cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieName] = cookie.name
                    if (cookie.name == "sessionid"){
                        return cookie.value
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ""
    }
```